# Show $\sum_{k=1}^n {k+1\choose 2}{2n+1\choose n+k+1}={n\choose 1}4^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

> I've been attempting to show that:
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^n {k+1\choose 2}{2n+1\choose n+k+1}={n\choose 1}4^{n-1}\\
> \sum_{k=2}^n {k+2\choose 4}{2n+1\choose n+k+1}={n\choose 2}4^{n-2}$$

Can anyone give some direction?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I could express ${2n+1\choose n+k+1}={2n+1\choose n-k}$ or rewrite using combination formula, but they do not cancel.

Comment: Have you tried by induction?

Comment: I don't think induction is a good idea with binomials

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Introducing_a_free_parameter_(snake_oil_method) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing we seek to verify that

$$S_{n,m} = \sum_{k=m}^n {k+m\choose 2m} {2n+1\choose n+k+1} =
{n\choose m} 4^{n-m}.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-m} {k+2m\choose 2m} {2n+1\choose n+m+k+1}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} {k+2m\choose 2m}
[z^{n-m-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+m+k+2}}
\\ = [z^{n-m}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+m+2}}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-m} {k+2m\choose 2m} \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k}.$$

Now when $k\gt n-m$ there is no contribution to the coefficient
extractor and we may continue with

$$[z^{n-m}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+m+2}}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+2m\choose 2m} \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k}
\\ = [z^{n-m}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+m+2}}
\frac{1}{(1-z/(1-z))^{2m+1}}
\\ = [z^{n-m}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^{2m+1}}.$$

This yields

$$S_{n,m} = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^{2m+1}}.$$

Residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is zero by inspection.
We get for the residue at $z=1$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1} \frac{1}{z^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^{2m+1}}.$$

Setting $z= 1-u$  we get

$$- \mathrm{Res}_{u=0} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{u^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2(1-u))^{2m+1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{u=0} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{u^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(2u-1)^{2m+1}}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{u=0} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{u^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2u)^{2m+1}}
= S_{n,m}.$$

Continuing with the residue at $z=1/2$ we find

$$-\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}} \mathrm{Res}_{z=1/2} \frac{1}{z^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(z-1/2)^{2m+1}}
\\ = -\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=1/2} \frac{1}{(1/2+(z-1/2))^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1/2-(z-1/2))^{n-m+1}}
\\ \times \frac{1}{(z-1/2)^{2m+1}}
\\ = -\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=1/2}
\frac{1}{(1/4-(z-1/2)^2)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(z-1/2)^{2m+1}}
\\ = -\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=1/2}
\frac{4^{n-m+1}}{(1-4(z-1/2)^2)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(z-1/2)^{2m+1}}
\\ = -\frac{2^{2n-2m+2}}{2^{2m+1}}
[(z-1/2)^{2m}] \frac{1}{(1-4(z-1/2)^2)^{n-m+1}}
\\ = -\frac{2^{2n-2m+2}}{2^{2m+1}}
[(z-1/2)^{m}] \frac{1}{(1-4(z-1/2))^{n-m+1}}
\\ = -\frac{2^{2n-2m+2}}{2^{2m+1}}
{m+n-m\choose n-m} 2^{2m}.$$

We have shown that

$$S_{n,m} + S_{n,m} - 2^{2n-2m+1} {n\choose m} = 0$$

which is at last

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S_{n,m} = {n\choose m} 4^{n-m}.}$$

Comment: Great answer. (+1)

Comment: Thanks, I enjoyed working on it. It has a nice symmetry.

Comment: Yes, the symmetry is nice. It seems to be somehow the generatingfunctionological pendant to the fact, that here we sum half of the terms $\binom{2n+1}{n+k+1}$, where $-n-1\le k \le n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rearrange the sum as
$$ 
\eqalign{ 
  & s(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( \matrix{ 
  k + 1 \cr  
  2 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{ 
  2n + 1 \cr  
  n + k + 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr  
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = \,0}^{n - 1} {\left( \matrix{ 
  k + 2 \cr  
  2 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{ 
  2n + 1 \cr  
  n + k + 2 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr  
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,} {\left( \matrix{ 
  k + 2 \cr  
  2 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{ 
  2n + 1 \cr  
  n + k + 2 \cr}  \right)}  \cr}  
$$

The summand is equal to 
$$ 
 \eqalign{ 
  & t_{\,k}  = \left( \matrix{  k + 2 \cr   2 \cr}  \right) 
 \left( \matrix{  2n + 1 \cr   n + k + 2 \cr}  \right) =   \cr  
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {k + 3} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + k + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)}} 
{{\Gamma \left( {2n + 2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 3 \right)}} \cr}  
$$
so that 
$$ 
t_{\,0}  = \left( \matrix{ 
  2n + 1 \cr  
  n + 2 \cr}  \right) = {{\Gamma \left( {2n + 2} \right)}  
 \over {\Gamma \left( {n + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( n \right)}} 
$$
and the ratio is
$$ 
\eqalign{ 
  & {{t_{\,k + 1} } \over {t_{\,k} }} =   \cr  
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {k + 4} \right)} 
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + k + 4} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - 1 - k} \right)}} 
 {{\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + k + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)} 
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 3} \right)}} =   \cr  
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {k + 4} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + k + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - k} \right)} 
 \over {\Gamma \left( {k + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( {k + 2} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + k + 4} \right)\Gamma \left( {n - 1 - k} \right)}} =   \cr  
  &  = {{\left( {k + 3} \right)\left( {n - 1 - k} \right)} \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {n + k + 3} \right)}} 
 =  - {{\left( {k + 3} \right)\left( {k - \left( {n - 1} \right)} \right)} \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {k + n + 3} \right)}} \cr}  
$$

That means that we can write $s(n))$ in terms of a [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)
$$ 
s(n) = {{\Gamma \left( {2n + 2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( n \right)}} 
{}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{ 
   {\;3,\; - \left( {n - 1} \right)}  \cr  
   {n + 3}  \cr  
 } \;} \right|\; - 1} \right) 
$$

Since
$$ 
1 + a - b = 1 + 3 + n - 1 = n + 3 = c 
$$
we can apply [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Kummer's_theorem_(z_=_%E2%88%921) 
and get 
$$ 
\eqalign{ 
  & s(n) = {{\Gamma \left( {2n + 2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( n \right)}}{}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{ 
   {\;3,\; - \left( {n - 1} \right)}  \cr  
   {n + 3}  \cr  
 } \;} \right|\; - 1} \right) =   \cr  
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {2n + 2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {n + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( n \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {n + 3} \right)\Gamma \left( {5/2} \right)} 
 \over {\Gamma \left( 4 \right)\Gamma \left( {3/2 + n} \right)}} =   \cr  
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {5/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 4 \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {2n + 2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( n \right)\Gamma \left( {3/2 + n} \right)}} \cr}  
$$

Then by the duplication formula 
$$ 
\Gamma \left( {2\,n + 2} \right) = 2^{\,2\,n + 1} {{\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 3/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}} 
$$
we finally reach to 
$$ 
\eqalign{ 
  & s(n) = {{\Gamma \left( {5/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 4 \right)\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 3/2} \right)} 
 \over {\Gamma \left( n \right)\Gamma \left( {3/2 + n} \right)}}2^{\,2\,n + 1}  =   \cr  
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {5/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( 4 \right)\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}n\,2^{\,2\,n + 1}  = {1 \over 8}n\,2^{\,2\,n + 1}  = n\,2^{\,2\,n - 2}  \cr}  
$$

Comment: Interesting approach. Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: Thanks Markus for the appreciation